# Having custom loading animation for IoS loading from server

Tags: iphone, animation, nsurldownload

I am porting an android application to iPhone. There is a custom alertdialog for android with custom animation for loading contents from the server. Can we replicate this on iPhone?? Kindly guide for the same and oblige.

Comment: Sure you can. What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I tred using MBProgressHUD library, it gives with the loading animation, but say i want a cookie animation where parts of the cookie biscuit is displayed proportional to the amount downloaded, is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

No for this we need to show alertDialog programatically in ios there is no available custom alertdialog use https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD it's good for showing alertDialog

Answer (score 1):

Look for an alert view implementation on github / cocoacontrols which allows you to add a custom subview and show an image animation there (using `UIImageView` and a set of images which are the frames of your animation).